# Lucene Field Grouping

Tags: lucene

say i m having fields stud_roll_number and date_leave.

**select stud_roll_number,count(*) from some_table where date_leave > some_date group by stud_roll_number;**

how to write the same query using Lucene....I tried after querying date_leave > some_date

for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {

```
    Document doc = search.doc(scoreDoc.doc);

String value = doc.get(fieldName);

Integer key = mapGrouper.get(value);

if (key == null) {
    key = 1;
} else {
    key = key+1;
}

mapGrouper.put(value, key);
```

}

But, I m having huge data set, it takes much time to compute this. Is there any other way to find it???? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your performance bottleneck is almost certainly the I/O it takes to perform the document and field value lookups.  What you want to do in this situation is use a FieldCache for the field you want to group by.  Once you have a field cache, you can look up the values by Lucene doc ID, which will be fast because all the values are in memory.

Also remember to give your HashMap an initial capacity to avoid array resizing.

Comment: Is there any example using FieldCache??? I searched, but sorry, i couldn't able to find it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a very new grouping module, on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1421 as a patch, that will do this.